# Error with using basic spring boot authentication

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am going through a spring security tutorial where I am trying to configure a basic security using the spring-boot-starter-security using the class like below

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.NoOpPasswordEncoder;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/","/api/*").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated().and().formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll()
                .and().logout().permitAll();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void ConfigureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().passwordEncoder(NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance())
                .withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER");
    }

}
```

But when I try to use the page localhost:8080 or localhost:8080/api/hello?name=test, it's not asking for login and directly showing the requested page. please help me with the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code allows access without authentication for / and /api/*

```
http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/","/api/*").permitAll()
```

It restricts access without authentication to any requests which are not matched with above url

```
.anyRequest().authenticated()
```

Comment: My requests are like below
1) localhost:8080/
2) localhost:8080/api/hello?name=test

so it should match the criteria right ?

Comment: It is matching criteria for not needing authentication

Comment: Add one more class in webservice `

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api2")
public class Greetings2 {

    @GetMapping("/hello")
    public String greet(@RequestParam(name = "name")String name){
        return "hello " + name;

    }
}`
This /api2/hello shall redirect you to login page

Comment: It's working fine after removing the antmatchers. thank you.